# How to find IMEI serial number on a WiFi Only Device

Tags: ipad, wifi, serial-number

I have a WiFi only 4th generation iPad and to trade my device in I am being asked for an IMEI serial number that you would dial for on your dialer. However, my iPad does not have a dialer, and I cannot find an IMEI in settings.

Can you help or is there no possible way to find this information?

Comment: WiFi iPads have no IMEI

Answer (score 1):

The settings app has a general section where you can get all the various MEID / IMEI / ICCID and serial numbers. If you are being forced to make up a number, perhaps the listing isnt correct for a WiFi only device or you need to find a seller that can properly classify your hardware as WiFi only.

If you did have a cellular capable iPad, and you can’t find the information in the about section, it might need a restore or repair.

Answer (score 1):

Only cellular devices have an IMEI (it stands for [International Mobile Equipment Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Equipment_Identity)). Also a dialer is only available on an iPhone (not on a cellular iPad).

In your case the only thing you could provide is the serial number, which you can discover in `Settings -> General -> About`. It can be used on Apple's [Check Coverage](https://checkcoverage.apple.com) page to verify purchase date and warranty coverage.